# Open links with Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter, automation

I'm just tinkering with some javascript and was wondering if there was a way to implement that when visiting your favorite site's twitter profile, it would go to the a link/links given in a tweet. Below I was checking the Verge and was wondering if there was any way to visit the url given in the first tweet without clicking it. I really intend to use this script almost as an index in which you can put a keyword in a variable and loop through the tweets for the specific word/variable string and it would open the link/links found in that tweet that matches your desired variable.

I did some digging and see that something along the lines of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    tweet[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text")[i].innerHTML;
}
```

would go through the first tweet and get the url link. I'm still unsure if this is the right way to go about this. I also don't know how to improve functionality in which if a tweet had two links it would open both or just one by using a match() to confine the opening of links only from [vrge.co](http://vrge.co)

[image]

For the particular timeline above, a variable would be set to something like "movies" or "'Anchorman" and when going to the Verge's twitter, the script would open that link in the tweet with the keywords, [vrge.co/1bIeqHe](http://vrge.co/1bIeqHe) 
Any insight would be really helpful. Thanks to all and happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

if you have the link you can just do a

```
window.location.href = linkvar;
```

See http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html for an example.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm unsure how to store the url in a variable. I mean understand I'll store it as a string and then use the line above, but I'm unsure as to how to grab the link from within the tweet. Does the code I use in the question work as far as singling the link out? I just threw that together because upon inspecting the page I saw the link in the js-tweet-text class. Also, how would I go about this if the tweet was to have two links embedded? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need another loop to go through all the links in each tweet, use the getAttribute method to get the destination of each link (href):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  tweet[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text")[i];

  var links = tweet[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
    var linkURL = links[j].getAttribute("href");

    //do something with linkURL here

  }
}
```

Note: You don't need to use the innerHTML attribute as you were, as that would treat the tweet as a string, rather than a JS object

**EDIT:** I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'as opposed to the embedded photo grid on the left of a twitter profile? ', but I think this should do what you want...

It will go through ALL tweets in a timeline (not just the visible ones) and pick out the links with classes 'media' and 'twitter-timeline-link' - this avoids hashtags and handles.

```
//Declare helpful functions to get elements by xpath
getElementsByXpath = function (path, doc = document) {
    return document.evaluate(path, doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
};

getElementByXpath = function (path, doc = document) {
    return document.evaluate(path, doc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
};

console.log("Starting...");

var tweetsXpath = "//li[contains(@id,'stream-item-tweet')]";
var linksXpath = "//a[contains(@class,'twitter-timeline-link') and contains(@class,'media')]";

var tweets = getElementsByXpath(tweetsXpath);

console.log("Tweets: " +tweets); //tweets is an XPathResult object. We can iterate over this.
var tweet = tweets.iterateNext(); //get first tweet
while(tweet != null){

    var links = getElementsByXpath(linksXpath, tweet);
    var link = links.iterateNext(); //get first link

    while(link != null) {
        var linkURL = link.getAttribute("href");

        //do something with linkURL here
        console.log("Found media link in tweet - URL: " + linkURL);

        link = links.iterateNext(); //move to next link
    }
    tweet = tweets.iterateNext(); //move to next tweet
}

console.log("Done");
```

If you only want to process the visible tweets, comment out these 4 lines :

```
var tweet = tweets.iterateNext(); //get first tweet
while(tweet != null){
...
    tweet = tweets.iterateNext(); //move to next tweet
}
```

and change

```
 var links = getElementsByXpath(linksXpath, tweet);
```

to just

```
 var links = getElementsByXpath(linksXpath);
```

Hope this is what your looking for

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is the general idea but this only opens the links of tweets that have an embedded photos. I used this and added a window open function using the linkURL where the stubbed section is but even when looping from 0 to 1, which I would assume is just the first tweet, the script opened a different past tweet because the most recent tweet didn't have a photo. Any thoughts on how to go about looping through the actual timeline as opposed to the embedded photo grid on the left of a twitter profile? Thanks!